# How to define an individual data type for each HDF5 column with h5py

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have checked different solutions, but could not understand how to apply them to multidimensional arrays. To be precise, my code results in a larger array than it should be, as shown in the picture below:

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861], [1583663558450195, -7.063664436340332, -6.2776079177856445, -4.206898212432861, -4.206898212432861]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

hf = h5py.File('dtype.h5', 'w')

dataTypes = np.dtype([('ts', 'u8'), ('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'), ('z', 'f4'), ('temp', 'f4')])
ds = hf.create_dataset('Acceleration', data=df.astype(dataTypes))
```

[image]

I would like to make it like this, where the columns are uint64, 4x float32 respectively:

```
                 ts         x         y         z      temp
0  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
1  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
2  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
3  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
4  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
5  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
6  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
7  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
8  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
9  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df`:

```
In [370]: df                                                                                   
Out[370]: 
                  0         1         2         3         4
0  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
1  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
2  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
3  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
...
```

`df.astype(dataTypes)` gives me a `TypeError` (my `pd` isn't the latest).

```
In [373]: df.to_records()                                                                      
Out[373]: 
rec.array([(0, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (1, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (2, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (3, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (4, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (5, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (6, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (7, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (8, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821),
           (9, 1583663558450195, -7.06366444, -6.27760792, -4.20689821, -4.20689821)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('0', '<i8'), ('1', '<f8'), ('2', '<f8'), ('3', '<f8'), ('4', '<f8')])
```

This array should save with `h5py`.

`to_records` has parameters that may create something closer to your `dataTypes`.  I'll let you explore those.

But with the latest restructuring a `recfunctions`, we can make a structured array with:

```
In [385]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf                                                  
In [386]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(np.array(data), dataTypes)                             
Out[386]: 
array([(1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898),
       (1583663558450195, -7.0636644, -6.277608, -4.206898, -4.206898)],
      dtype=[('ts', '<u8'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('temp', '<f4')])
```

`np.array(data)` is (10,5) float array.

```
In [388]: pd.DataFrame(_386)                                                                   
Out[388]: 
                 ts         x         y         z      temp
0  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
1  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
2  1583663558450195 -7.063664 -6.277608 -4.206898 -4.206898
 ...
```

Comment: Did you examine `df.astype(dataTypes)`?  Your image looks a lot like `np.array(data, dtype=dataTypes)`.  The `data` for a structured array is supposed to be a list of tuples, not a list of lists, as in  `np.array([tuple(i) for i in data], dtype=dataTypes)`

Answer (score 1):

This question is trickier than it first appears. Initially, I thought I could apply the same method as my answer to your previous question [SO 60562311:define individual datatypes for each column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60566679/10462884). However, it has some subtle differences:

1. This data is a List of Lists VS a 5x5 NumPy array
2. This data is of mixed type (Ints and Floats) VS all Floats
3. This data has more significant figures than the previous example

How does this change the procedure?

- The List of Lists can be converted to a NumPy array with
  `np.array(data)` However, that doesn't completely solve the problem. You will still get duplicated columns.
- You also need to change the object type in your dtype declaration. `f4`needs to be `f8`, and `u8` needs to be `uint16`

Make those changes, and everything works like my previous answer. See update to your original code below.

```
dataTypes = np.dtype([('ts', 'uint16'), ('x', 'f8'), 
            ('y', 'f8'), ('z', 'f8'), ('temp', 'f8')])
# create array from list of lists
d_arr = np.array(data) 
# create record array
rec_arr = np.rec.array(d_arr, dtype=dataTypes)
with h5py.File('dtype.h5', 'w') as hf:
    ds = hf.create_dataset('Acceleration', data=rec_arr)
```

Comment: I have been scratching my head since yesterday why after assigning column names all columns appear under a single column 0. And would you also tell why `f4` needs to be `f8`?

Comment: Good question. It took a while to figure that out and I'm not entirely sure. :-) I suspect it has to do with the number of significant figures in your data AND the conversion of `float64` to unsigned integer when creating the record array. In my code, it starts with the  `np.array(data)` call. The resulting dtype for `d_arr` is `float64`  If you convert the list into `float32`(`f4`) you lose half of your significant figures. Also, converting `float64` to`u8` results in a warning about "changing to a larger dtype". I suspect that's what triggers the multiple columns.

Comment: One more thought: `rf.unstructured_to_structured()' from `recfunctions` appears to handle this cleanly. This is new for me, so I need to investigate.